# Delete everything in second column not in parentheses

Tags: notepad++, regex, csv

I have a file that looks like this:

```
gene ID              protein
Solyc06g062540    (Z) PYROPHOSPHATASE 3 (PTHR20889:SF0)
Solyc10g075050    ALBUMIN SUPERFAMILY (PTHR33076:SF11)
Solyc07g061760    SUBFAMILY (PTHR24177:SF35)
```

The file is tab delimited; there is a tab between the first column (gene ID) and the second column (protein name). (The protein name can contain spaces, but not tabs.) The protein name contains a string in parentheses, e.g., `(PTHR33076:SF11)`; this is the protein *ID*. I want to keep the first column and delete everything in the second column except the protein ID (and its enclosing parentheses). So the output would look like:

```
Solyc06g062540    (PTHR20889:SF0)
Solyc10g075050    (PTHR33076:SF11)
Solyc07g061760    (PTHR24177:SF35)
```

How can I do this? I had marked all of the IDs in parentheses using the "mark" function and inputting `(\w+\d+:\w+\d+)` to highlight all of the IDs in parentheses, but I can't manipulate it. As a note, some of the protein names do have other parenthesized strings (e.g., see the first row, where the protein name contains `(Z)` as well as the ID value that I want). I do not want to keep those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a regular expression search and replace. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to open the Replace dialog. Make sure search mode is `Regular Expression`.

Find what:

```
(^[^\t\r\n]+\t)[^\t\r\n]+(\(\w+\d+:\w+\d+\))[^\t\r\n]*
```

Replace with:

```
\1\2
```

Explanation of the pattern:

`[^\t\r\n]+` is any string of characters that doesn't contain a tab or newline or carriage returns. This should match only the text in one column of your file.

`^[^\t\r\n]+` matches the content of the first column because the leading `^` limits the match to the start of a line.

The first capturing group `(^[^\t\r\n]+\t)` matches the contents of the first field and the following tab.

`[^\t\r\n]+(\(\w+\d+:\w+\d+\))[^\t\r\n]*` matches the contents of the second field and only matches if the parenthetical expression is present.

The second capturing group `(\(\w+\d+:\w+\d+\))` matches the parenthetical expression.

The replacement pattern `\1\2` returns the first and second capturing groups. This effectively deletes the surrounding text in the second field because that part of the match is not included in a capturing group.

Comment: This worked like a freaking charm. I just started using notepad ++ maybe an hour ago, and I can't believe how powerful it can be with text editing. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

If the (parenthesized) protein ID is always the last thing on the line
(as you've shown), it should be good enough to search for `\t.*(`
(or possibly `\t[^\r\n]*(`) and replace it with `\t(`.